# Machine Learning Data Cleaning: Removing unit of a value from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am practicing data cleaning on a dataset. It has one of the attribute 'mileage' which has value ending with unit 'km/kg' or 'kmpl' (eg : 23.4 kmpl , 17.3 km/kg).

To covert to numeric I used the code

```
df['mileage'] = df['mileage'].str.replace('kmpl','')
```

The above code works and it removes 'kmpl' but when I tried to remove 'km/kg' by replacing 'kmpl' with 'km/kg' it's not working. Neither it shows any error.

Can anyone suggest why this happens so? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code you used to replace 'kmpl' with 'km/kg'? What is the output you're getting now?

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'mileage':['23 kmpl', '22 kmpl']})
df['mileage'] = df['mileage'].str.replace('kmpl','km/kg')` -- This works for me